# jQuery-UI draggable cloning - Does the start handler receive any reference to the element being cloned?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone, draggable

Say I'm cloning element DIV_1.

In the draggable's start event handler, I need to select every element except DIV_1.

I sense there's no direct way to do that, so my plan was to select every element, then loop through them and eliminate the one that's the origin of the clone.

But without a way to reference DIV_1 from draggable start, I have nothing to compare the selected elements to.  And the ID isn't cloned so I can't use that.

(This is to enable multidragging/multicloning with some custom behavior.  Without filtering, when I clone every selected element I also clone the one that was just cloned.)

(My backup plan is to implement cloning on my own and simply bypass draggable's cloning, in which case there won't be any duplicate clones running around causing any problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out.

First, the "event" parameter includes at least three useful properties: target, currentTarget, and something else.  Looping through the properties and spitting out the target ones until you find objects will show them.  They refer to the original element, according to their "id" property.

So "event.currentTarget.id" or such.

But even that wasn't necessary.

I was using existing code which was comparing "$(ui.helper).attr('id')" to '$(this).attr("id")' within an "each" handler within start.  Obviously, "this" in that scope refers to something different from "this" within the parent scope of the start handler.

So when I switched the code over to cloning mode, I missed that connection and got confused.

$(this).attr("id") in the opening of the start handler, even during a clone, will provide the origin's ID, rather than $(ui.helper).attr("id"), which provides the clone's ID.

I obtained that value and used it within the "each" handler and everything worked perfectly.

Thanks!